# The integral of a non-negative function over a bounded domain attains its maximum iff the domain is an open ball?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> I'm studying the PDE book written by Gilbarg and Trudinger, and the inequality circled in red ink (pictured) makes me confused:

[image]

> Here $B_R(x)$ denotes the open ball of radius $R$ and center $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also note that the ball is chosen so that its volume is identical to that of $\Omega$. I don't know how to prove my assertion (as the title). Help me, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, substitute $y'=x-y$ to translate the ball and get rid of the $x$. The two regions of integration are now $\Omega'$ and $B_R(0)$. Next decompose each of the integrals into the 2 regions $\Omega' \cap B_R(0)$ and $\Omega' \setminus B_R(0)$ for the left side and $\Omega' \cap B_R(0)$ and $B_R(0) \setminus \Omega'$  for the right side. Cancel the identical integral over $\Omega' \cap B_R(0)$. We are left to show $$\int_{\Omega' \setminus B_R(0)}|y|^{n(\mu-1)}dy \le \int_{B_R(0) \setminus \Omega'}|y|^{n(\mu-1)}dy$$
That is we want to compare the integral of the same function over two regions of the same area, one of them inside $B_R(0)$, the other one outside. Note that the exponent $n(\mu-1)$ is always negative. Hence the function to be integrated is bigger than $R^{n(\mu-1)}$ inside of $B_R(0)$ and smaller than $R^{n(\mu-1)}$ outside so we can estimate:
$$\int_{\Omega' \setminus B_R(0)}|y|^{n(\mu-1)}dy \le \int_{\Omega' \setminus B_R(0)}R^{n(\mu-1)}dy=\int_{B_R(0) \setminus \Omega'}R^{n(\mu-1)}dy \le\int_{B_R(0) \setminus \Omega'}|y|^{n(\mu-1)}dy$$

Comment: Thank you. Does $\Omega'$ involved in $\int_{\Omega}|x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\Omega'}|y'|^{n(\mu-1)}\mathrm{d}y'$ matter in our calculation?

Comment: What's your $\Omega'$ in $\int_{\Omega}|x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\Omega'}|y'|^{n(\mu-1)}\mathrm{d}y'$?

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand. Could you write down the calculation in details?

Comment: Your argument is clear. The only thing that bothers me is whether the variable $y$ should be replaced with the variable $y'$. Is that right?

Comment: @Steve Technically it should be $y'$, I just found it easier to read to call the new variable $y$ as well.